# Is it safe to install Linux kernel 3.12?

Tags: kernel, updates, 13.10

Linux kernel 3.12 has been released but it's not available in Ubuntu's Software Updater. I can install it [using this guide](http://easytricksportal.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-install-upgrade-kernel-3121.html), but is it safe to install? I mean will it be as stable as 3.11? My current system is Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit with kernel 3.11.

Comment: Get it Here [Mainline kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything you install outside of Ubuntu oficial repositories you are on your own.

If it works for you, good.

According to [the Ubuntu wiki on mainline builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

> The mainline kernels builds are produced for debugging purposes and therefore come with no support. Use them at your own risk.

They don't include the extra patches/drivers included in Ubuntu kernels, so you may experience some issues.

Comment: But look at the link i provided ( http://goo.gl/nCTbFl ), the .deb packages are given from kernel.ubuntu.com people installed it successfully but my question is will it stable?

Comment: It is stable in the opinion of the kernel developers. It is not tested by the Ubuntu developers. And as Angel says, distributions add things to kernels that are not in the mainline sometime; could be drivers, subsystem or similar things that are still not accepted upstream. So it may work or not.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**, kernel 3.12.1 has been [officially released](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and is no longer an `rc`.